Let $f(x):\mathbb{R}\to [-1,1]$ be twice differentiable and $f(0)^2+f'(0)^2=4$, then p.t. $\exists x_0$ s.t. $f(x_0)+f''(x_0)=0$ but $f'(x_0)\ne 0$
The actual question is a multiple correct MCQ, but this was the only part I was having trouble with. I also can't fully attest for the correctness of the question, although my answer key does put this as a correct choice.
I take $g(x)=f(x)+f''(x)$ and $h(x)=f(x)^2+f'(x)^2$ (Note that $h(0)=4$) to get $$h'(x)=2f'(x)g(x)$$ To frame the question differently, we need to prove that there exists a critical point of $h(x)$ which is not a critical point of $f(x)$. Some other conclusions I've made: $$f(x)^2\le 1\implies h(x)\le 1+f'(x)^2$$ and, we also need to prove that $h'(x)=0$ for some $x$. I'm lost after this point, I have no idea how to approach this further. Any help is appreciated!

This is a previous putnam problem with a variation in JEE adv 2018 repeat

the adv problem is significantly easier since they give $f(0)^2+f'(0)^2=85$

@RandomGuy isn't this different though? Here we also need to prove that $f'(x_0)$ is non-zero at the same point when $g(x_0)=0$ which doesn't seem straightforward..

ok ye your question feels like a weird blend of both the $f'(x_o)\neq0$ is in the adv question and its easy to prove since u find that $x_o$ is not a maxima im not entirely sure how it would work in yours could u provide the source of the question?

@RandomGuy the source is my coaching material..

ah fellow aspirant finished my advanced this yr

Let $m$ be an arbitrary positive real number
By L.M.V.T in $[0,m]$ for $f$ we have
$$
\frac{f(m)-f(0)}{m}=f'(x_1)
$$
Since $f$ is bounded on $\mathbb{R}$ we have $-2\le f(m)-f(0)\le(1)-(-1)=2$
So there exists $x_1$ in $[0,m]$ and similarly and $x_2$ in $[-m,0]$ such that they satisfy
$$|f'(x)|<2m$$
Now we define $$g(x)=f'(x)^2+f(x)^2$$
We immediately have $g(0)=4$, $g(x_1)\le4m^2+1$
For $m<\frac{\sqrt{3}}2$ we have $g(0)>g(x_1), g(0)>g(x_2)$
By the Extreme-Value-Theorem for $g$ on $[x_2,x_1]$ it attains a maximum value at say $x_0$ so we have $g(x_0)\ge g(0) = 4$
This means $g'(x_0)=0$ and $g(x_0)\ge4$
If $f'(x_0)=0$ we have $g(x_0)=f(x_0)^2+0^2\ge4$ which is not possible so $f'(x_0)\neq4$ which implies $$f(x_0)+f''(x_0)=0$$
